# How to return a row if another row in a sequence does not follow SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the following scenario, and the only way I can think of doing this is to pull back all the data into a temp table and then use a cursor to loop through it, updating a record or the last record depending on the current record.

Basically, if an action called clarification happens I want to return this record, but if a clarification hold happens after a clarification then I don't want the clarification returned.

Now the thing is, any number of clarifications could happen in a row without a clarification hold, so if 5 clarifications happened and then one hold, I would want to return 4 records. A clarification can also happen after the hold, in this case I would want to show the clarification.

Anyone with any suggestions to a better solution than a cursor?

Comment: Can you provide some information about your data structures?

Comment: Its a sql server 2005 database with all the information on the one table. These are the fields that its using source_workobj_id int
action_log_id     int
action_typ_cd char(8)
from_queue_cd char(8)
to_queue_cd  char(8)
lst_upd_dtm   datetime

Comment: Something should be possible with a temp table, LEAD/LAG functions OVER partition. But I'm not sure if those work on SQL Server 2005 and can't test it right currently.

Comment: @user1103990: `LEAD`/`LAG` are available in **2012** and newer only

Answer (score 2):

I have made assumptions about your data structure, but the theory should still be applicable for you

```
-- Example table
DECLARE @t table (
   action_description   char(20)
 , when_occured         datetime
);

-- Set up data
INSERT INTO @t (action_description, when_occured)
  VALUES ('clarification'     , DateAdd(mi, -9, Current_Timestamp)) -- Include
       , ('clarification'     , DateAdd(mi, -8, Current_Timestamp)) -- Include
       , ('clarification'     , DateAdd(mi, -7, Current_Timestamp)) -- Include
       , ('clarification'     , DateAdd(mi, -6, Current_Timestamp))
       , ('clarification hold', DateAdd(mi, -5, Current_Timestamp))
       , ('clarification'     , DateAdd(mi, -4, Current_Timestamp)) -- Include
       , ('clarification'     , DateAdd(mi, -3, Current_Timestamp)) -- Include
       , ('clarification'     , DateAdd(mi, -2, Current_Timestamp)) -- Include
       , ('clarification'     , DateAdd(mi, -1, Current_Timestamp)) -- Include
       , ('clarification'     , DateAdd(mi,  0, Current_Timestamp)) -- Include
       , ('clarification'     , DateAdd(mi, +1, Current_Timestamp))
       , ('clarification hold', DateAdd(mi, +2, Current_Timestamp))
       , ('clarification'     , DateAdd(mi, +3, Current_Timestamp)) -- Include
       , ('clarification'     , DateAdd(mi, +4, Current_Timestamp))
       , ('clarification hold', DateAdd(mi, +5, Current_Timestamp))
       , ('clarification hold', DateAdd(mi, +6, Current_Timestamp))
       , ('clarification'     , DateAdd(mi, +7, Current_Timestamp)) -- Include
       , ('clarification'     , DateAdd(mi, +8, Current_Timestamp))
       , ('clarification hold', DateAdd(mi, +9, Current_Timestamp));

; WITH all_actions AS (
  SELECT action_description
       , when_occured
       , Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY when_occured) As row_num -- Provide a sequence for joining
  FROM   @t
)
SELECT a1.action_description
     , a1.when_occured
FROM   all_actions As a1
 LEFT
  JOIN all_actions As a2                            -- Join back to self
    ON a2.row_num = a1.row_num + 1                  -- on previous row
   AND a2.action_description = 'clarification hold' -- where the previous row had this action
WHERE  a1.action_description = 'clarification' -- Only want to show clarification actions
AND    a2.action_description IS NULL           --  and exclude those who had a row in the join
```

Comment: Thanks gvee, I had never come accross WITH all_actions before. Works like a dream

Comment: The `WITH` keyword in this context signifies the start of a **Common Table Expression** (or CTE for short). You can read about them _[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)_.